# Django app works fine, but getting a TEMPLATE_* warning message

Tags: python, django, django-1.8

When I use runserver, it gives this warning message:

> (1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in
>   Django 1.8 and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes precedence. You must put
>   the values of the following settings into your default TEMPLATES dict:
>   TEMPLATE_DEBUG.

Quoth the Django Documentation:

> "TEMPLATE_DEBUG Deprecated since version 1.8: Set the 'debug' option
>   in the OPTIONS of a DjangoTemplates backend instead."

Here is my settings.py with my futile attempts to fix it:

```
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myapp/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'debug': DEBUG,
            'DEBUG': DEBUG,
            'TEMPLATE_DEBUG': DEBUG
        },
    }, ]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's just a message. It's recommending you do not use TEMPLATE_DEBUG.

Comment: @Gocht  Thank you. What is the correct way to enter this value in the TEMPLATES dict? I just commented out the lines I added to the dict and debug seems to work fine. Is it really even necessary to add anything to this dict?

Comment: It is necessary if you want to keep your code up to date. @Alasdair has given you a good answer.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Set `debug` in `OPTIONS` dictionary of your templates settings.

```
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
        },
    },
]
```

Then remove this line from your settings to stop the warnings

```
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
```

See the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/upgrading/) for detailed instructions how to update your template settings.

Answer (score 15):

remove APP_DIRS and add the loaders inside the templates. 
example:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'loaders': [
               'django_jinja.loaders.AppLoader',
                'django_jinja.loaders.FileSystemLoader',
            ]
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 14):

From *settings.py* remove all this:

```
    TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
    )
```

Then add *'templates'* here:

```
    TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [here],
        ...
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 8):

This is the best solution:

Change this line to:

```
TEMPLATES[0]['OPTIONS']['debug'] = True
```

which should fix the warning.

I have found it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/wagtail/cLImH-XhXFI/9UebbCngBAAJ).

Comment: Change this line to: "TEMPLATES[0]['OPTIONS']['debug'] = True" in <project name>/settings/dev.py

Answer (score 1):

In my `setting.py` in `django`, there is not this script :

`TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG`

and

`'debug': DEBUG,
            'DEBUG': DEBUG,
            'TEMPLATE_DEBUG': DEBUG`

Maybe you can try to remove them and run it again.